# Business and Customer app in a single project in Kotlin Multiplatform?

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am making an app that connects customers and businesses. Now I'd like to pack it into a single project as they are thematically connected and might share some of the logic. This would be simple enough with a native app but for multiplatform I am unsure as how to have them organized. Eg I'd have two IOS and two Android modules, but for the shared code, I'd need 3 shared libraries, sharedBussiness, sharedCustomer and common. Would this seperation be too difficult to handle when it comes to generating frameworks and dependencies? As the sharedBusiness/ Customer would depend on the common module, and on the ios side there are frameworks that have to be generated and handled. Is this a common approach/ would it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work without any problems. If you split your code in many modules, you can include only needed ones for each platform or app.

It's not that easy to add many KMM modules to an iOS app, but you don't need to.

So your may have `sharedBusiness` and `sharedCustomer` KMM modules, each included by a corresponding application, and both may be just a combination of other KMM modules, depend on `common` in your case.

By default it'll only export classes used by headers of the `shared` module.

Like, if you have `data class SharedBusiness(let common: SomeCommonClass)`, the `SomeCommonClass` will be exported, otherwise - it'll not.

So if you need to export all classes and functions from `common` module to iOS framework, you can do it using [this docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-build-native-binaries.html#export-dependencies-to-binaries)

Comment: Just to clarify, the common would be also a KMM class and it would work as described? As common would have to have networking and some other platform specific implementations. Now that I think about it, it may not be necessary to be a KMM module but just to make sure how it would work

Comment: @Nikola-Milovic not sure I've got it. If you wanna use some kotlin code in iOS, it should be in KMM module, otherwise - yes, you can simply use android library or java library

Comment: Sorry I haven't clarified it. I thought about whether or not the Common Module can also be a KMM? Can the Bussiness/CustomerShared module implement another KotlinMultiplatform Module for example?

Comment: @Nikola-Milovic yes, KMM module can easily depend on an other KMM module. The only restriction is that the dependency has to have support all platforms your main module is supporting.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Android Build variant (`productFlavor`), You would have 1 Main source code with the shared logic, and then you create new package one for your Customer and one for your Business and inside you put the difference code only.

to read more check this out [build-variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)